# How to split a string if the rule is ", {CAPITAL LETTER}"

Tags: php

I'm wondering how to split the following string into the array:

*Training bench with two arm curlers, leg curler and barbell rack, Max. load: 160kg*

The output should be:

```
array (
[0] => 'Training bench with two arm curlers, leg curler and barbell rack',
[1] => 'Max. load: 160kg'
);
```

The rule can be '**, {CAPITAL LETTER}**' (comma + space + capital letter).
In this case '***, M***'

Could you advise me?

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Not just post a question and look for someone help you finish your homework. At least you should have a thought on how to get it in ways, e.g. substring? detect Capital letter, Regex?

Comment: You could use `explode(',',$my_string)` then check the first letter if capitalized, else append to previous...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as requested

```
$str = "Training bench with two arm curlers, leg curler and barbell rack, Max. load: 160kg";
print_r(preg_split('/\,\ (?=[A-Z])/m',$str));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Training bench with two arm curlers, leg curler and barbell rack
    [1] => Max. load: 160kg
)
```